# Is it possible to write multiple regex for the same input in Fluent Bit?

Tags: regex, parsing, fluentd, grok, fluent-bit

My logs look like this:

```
200 59903 0.056 - [24/Jun/2020:00:06:56 +0530] "GET /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx HTTP/1.1" xxxxx.com [xxxx:4900:xxxx:b798:xxxx:c8ba:xxxx:6a23] - - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - -  "http://xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx" 164551836 1 HIT "-" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Mi A1 Build/PKQ1.180917.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/77.0.3865.92 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-" "-" "dhDebug=-" "-" - -
200 11485 0.000 - [24/Jun/2020:00:06:56 +0530] "GET /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx HTTP/1.1" xxxxx.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - -  "-" 164551710 7 HIT "-" "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; vivo 1915 Build/PPR1.180610.011)" "-" "-" "dhDebug=appVersion=13.0.8&osVersion=9&clientId=1271210612&conn_type=4G&conn_quality=NO_CONNECTION&sessionSource=organic&featureMask=1879044085&featureMaskV1=635" "-" 40 -
```

The two logs are almost same except the fact that the last one contains a detailed output of `dhDebug`.

This is how my `parsers.conf` looks like:

```
[PARSER]
    Name         head
    Format       regex
    Regex        (?<responseCode>\d{3})\s(?<responseSize>\d+)\s(?<responseTime>\d+.\d+)\s.*?\s\[(?<time>.*?)\]\s"(?<method>.*?)\s(?<url1>.*?)\s(?<protocol>.*?)"\s(?<servedBy>.*?)\s(?<Akamai_ip1>.*?)\s(?<ClientId_ip2>.*?)\s(?<ip3>.*?)\s(?<lb_ip4>.*?)\s(?<ip5>.*?)\s(?<ip6>.*?)\s(?<ip7>.*?)\s+"(?<url2>.*?)".*?".*?"\s".*?"\s"(?<agentInfo>.*?)"
    Time_Key     time
    Time_Format  %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    Time_Keep    On
    Types responseTime:float
```

Please suggest any idea on how to implement the information of `dhDebug` in a separate key-value pair in the same regex that works on both the types of logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED!!

You can use `(?:case1|case2)` for case1: is null and case2: is not null

So Regex will be:

```
(?<responseCode>\d{3})\s(?<responseSize>\d+)\s(?<responseTime>\d+.\d+)\s.*?\s\[(?<time>.*?)\]\s"(?<method>.*?)\s(?<url1>.*?)\s(?<protocol>.*?)"\s(?<servedBy>.*?)\s(?<Akamai_ip1>.*?)\s(?<ClientId_ip2>.*?)\s(?<ip3>.*?)\s(?<lb_ip4>.*?)\s(?<ip5>.*?)\s(?<ip6>.*?)\s(?<ip7>.*?)\s+"(?<url2>.*?)".*?".*?"\s".*?"\s"(?<agentInfo>.*?)"\s"-"\s"-"\s"dhDebug=(?:-|appVersion=(?<appVersion>.*?)&osVersion=(?<osVersion>.*?)&clientId=(?<clientId>.*?)&conn_type=(?<conn_type>.*?)&conn_quality=(?<conn_quality>.*?)&sessionSource=(?<sessionSource>.*?)&featureMask=(?<featureMask>.*?)&featureMaskV1=(?<featureMaskV1>.*?))"
```

With this you get null for each field name of dhDebug for the first log line and field names with values for the second one.

You can test it at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I know this but my problem is individually parsing fields inside `dhDebug` like `clientId` and `appVersion` while making sure the grok parses logs that have an empty `dhDeubg` as well.